# Proper way to use Gaussian Process results

Tags: gaussian-process

This is my first time using ML. In the past I only used polynomial fitting to describe my test results, and I used those polynomial mainly as deliverables to other teams for use in their work.

Now I have used Gaussian Process for the first time with GPML. It seems to produce good results but I am a little confused on what is the best/proper way to share it?
With a fitted polynomial I could just share a simple function or coefficients. With GP it seems I would need to first decide on a set of desired query points and then share a large results set of those points to my colleagues. Does any one have a better suggestion on how to easily utilize the results?

Thank you